# Rails Fixtures not loading with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, fixtures

So, I'm trying to learn the rspec BDD testing framework in the context of a rails project.  The problem I'm having is that I can't, for the life of me, get my fixtures to load properly in rspec descriptions.

Disclaimer: Yes, there are better things than fixtures to use.  I'm trying to learn one thing at a time, here (specifically rspec) before I go play with associated tools like factory-girl, mocha, auto-test, etc.  As such, I'm trying to get the dead-simple, if clunky, fixtures working.

Anyway, here's the code:

/test/fixtures/users.yml -

```
# password: "secret"
foo:
  username: foo
  email: foo@example.com
  password_hash: 3488f5f7efecab14b91eb96169e5e1ee518a569f
  password_salt: bef65e058905c379436d80d1a32e7374b139e7b0

bar:
  username: bar
  email: bar@example.com
  password_hash: 3488f5f7efecab14b91eb96169e5e1ee518a569f
  password_salt: bef65e058905c379436d80d1a32e7374b139e7b0
```

/spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb -

```
require 'spec/spec_helper'

describe PagesController do
  integrate_views
  fixtures :users
  it "should render index template on index call when logged in" do
    session[:user_id] = user(:foo).id
    get 'index' 
    response.should render_template('index')
  end
end
```

And what I'm getting when I run 'rake spec' is:

```
NoMethodError in 'PagesController should render index template on index call when logged in'
undefined method `user' for #<Spec::Rails::Example::ControllerExampleGroup::Subclass_1:0x2405a7c>
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/test_process.rb:511:in `method_missing'
./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:7:
```

That is, it's not recognizing 'user(:foo)' as a valid method.

The fixtures themselves must be ok, since when I load them into the development db via 'rake db:fixtures:load', I can verify that foo and bar are present in that db.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious here, but I've been tearing my hair out all day to no avail.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you using the fixtures from test/fixtures inside Rspec? Would you mind sharing this with us

Comment: This question is 10 years old.  When I first asked it, I was learning rails for the first time (probably rails 2!).  Since then I've graduated college, worked at 3 jobs, spoken at rubyconf, and been employed fulltime as a rails dev for ~6 years.  I would humbly suggest that perhaps this question is no longer relevant, either to me or to the wider world.  :)

Comment: hahahhah
So as an experienced developer, ure saying that fixtures have a better alternative? :)

Comment: Not sure why fixtures gets all this hate? Fixtures are good enough for a business like basecamp who've collected over +$100m in revenue over the last 20 years. my two cents - It cannot be all that bad.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you define fixtures as 'users', then the way to use them is via the method with the same name:

```
describe PagesController do
  integrate_views
  fixtures :users
  it "should render index template on index call when logged in" do
    session[:user_id] = users(:foo).id
    get 'index'
    response.should render_template('index')
  end
end
```

The singular is only relevant to the class itself (User). Hope you still have some hair left if this is just a one letter bug.

Comment: Damnit.  Well, I was sure it was something that stupid, and I was was damn right.  Thanks, that solved it.  :)

Answer (score 18):

If you want to set up your fixtures globally, inside your `spec_helper` or `rails_helper` you can add:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.global_fixtures = :all
end
```

Comment: It works, but I have to write it in `rails_helper`.

Answer (score 2):

It took me a really long time to figure this out myself.

```
# spec/rails_helper.rb

RSpec.configure do |config|
#  config.file_fixture_path = Rails.root / 'test' / 'fixtures' # <= incorrect
  config.fixture_path = Rails.root / 'test' / 'fixtures'
```

then, as stated on other comments, use

```
RSpec.describe 'Events API', type: :request do
  fixtures :events
```

Comment: Thanks. This helped me fix `No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /opt/app/spec/fixtures/my_fixture.yml`