# How to seed the test database before to run Cucumber features?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, rspec-rails

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2, cucumber-rails-1.3.0 and rspec-rails-2.8.1. Since I have some "system" data stored in the database, and since I would like to test my application that needs that data in order to properly work, *I would like to **seed** the **test** database before to run Cucumber features*.

**How can I make that? What do you advice about?**

Comment: that depends largelt on your deployment ands testing process and toools.  FOr instance i use simple groovy scripts to dump some SQL into my database when it starts.

Comment: @Eddie - What are those "groovy scripts"? Where I should put those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails has a feature called [Fixtures](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/Fixtures.html) which prepopulates the test database before testing. Fixtures uses YAML to seed a table of the same name with data.

The Ruby on Rails guides have a [low down on fixtures](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#the-low-down-on-fixtures) that may be beneficial to have a look at.

Comment: I am not using Test::Unit, but RSpec and Cucumber. It works for those gems?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you, I should learn to read. Someone appears to have success with fixures and rspec [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976832/rails-fixtures-not-loading-with-rspec). But the 7th post in [this thread](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/167716) may be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Thare is also FactoryGirl.
It can read from any place but generally uses features/factories.rb or features/factories/*.rb

[See RailsCast 275](http://railscasts.com/episodes/275-how-i-test). Ryan uses it with RSpec, but the principles are the same. Note FactoryGirl has had a major revision since then, so all the API has evolved.